# find different value in scope term

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have a this code

```
$scope.term = value1;
$scope.term = value2;
$scope.term = value3;
$scope.term = value1;
```

Is there a opportunity to find all different value from the $scope.term ? In the example the result is (value1 and value2)
I need this to give the user the opportunity to filter and ng-repeat section with dynamically build buttons.

Thanks for your help
Stefan

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... how is the result `value1` and `value2`?

Comment: I want to replay all different value from the $scope.term.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for

```
$scope.term = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value1'];
```

You just need to put all options in an array.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is not what I look for.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is not what I look for.
I want ask the $skope.term what different vale he has.
So I can build buttons to filter an ng-repeat

    <div ng-repeat=”term in terms | filter:buttonvalue”>
{{term}}
    </div>

But I don’t can hardcode the filter value (button value). When $scope.term has 2 different value there will setup 2 buttons and by 10 different value there will 10 buttons. 
For me is important that will all setup dynamically,